# Best Way to Organize JavaScript Files

Tags: javascript, file, preload

So I have web app with multiple JS files (jQuery, jQuery, my own JS code and more). Say I have a page named index.html. What would be the best practice to include / preload my js files? I was thinking about creating a separate JS file that will do the preloading (include all the other scripts and call jQuery.noConflict()). What do you guys suggest? Is this possible? How would you implement it?

Thanks!

Comment: What is speaking against just including them in the `head` section? The browser will take care of the caching.

Comment: If you have a lot of files, don't put them in the head. Put them at the end of the body. Create a page that looks nice without the files and then add them at the end of the body. The page you create will serve as a splash page. You can hide your splash elements once jquery loads.

Comment: @Pekka: Putting scripts in the `head` is only necessary if you use their functionality during the rendering of `body`, and slows down the perceived load-time of the page. If you don't need their functionality *during rendering* (and that includes the user clicking things while the page is still being built), put them at the bottom of `body`. [More](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Answer (score 7):

In general, combine your script files into one file (and [minify](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) or [compress](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) them, or even [*compile*](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) them, but note that this last item is *not* zero-impact, there are pain points). See notes [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and [here](http://code.google.com/speed/articles/). Basically, one of the first guidelines you'll see for a good fast page load is "minimize HTTP requests." So you don't want six separate `script` tags where you could have one.

For popular scripts, though, you *may* benefit from using them from [Google's CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/). Google is kind enough to host most popular JavaScript libraries on their CDN for free. The advantage here being not only that the CDN will be fairly fast, but that the target user's browser may well have a cached version of the script you want to use even though they've never been to *your* site before.

Comment: can you explain more "but note that this last item is not zero-impact, there are pain points" ? thanks

Comment: @Oddant: Using the Closure compiler requires some source-level practices that just minifiers/compressors don't usually require. But in its Simple mode, they're not at all onerous. (Advanced mode is more hassle -- but then, you get more benefit as well.)

Answer (score 5):

Check out [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), a smart and robust script loader for JavaScript. It's designed to work well with jQuery and comes with an [optimization tool](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) to combine all of your scripts into one.

Comment: +1 It's particularly handy in app dev. I really like the module pattern in uses.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to minimize all the js files and combine them into one script.  This will cause less work for the browser, as it doesn't have to make multiple requests to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to load everything up at the same time, you could put it all into a single compressed file

Comment: ^^^ yep google closure compiler is the way to go...I believe this is what jQuery itself is compressed with.

Comment: Enjoy the pain of supporting compressed code. If your page loads fast enough without compression or you can turn on gzip on your server, don't compress, just concatenate. Even concatenation makes it hard to debug.

Comment: As far as supporting the compressed code, I thinking maintaining a compressed and uncompressed version is the way to go...only using the compressed version for production

Comment: @stephen I find that reality intrudes and I end up struggling to reproduce errors being reported by my production system with stack traces full of variables named a,b and c all on line 0. Of course, if you don't get all the js errors emailed to you, or you have a QA team you won't suffer that way...